# new version of android app with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, version

I already made and published an app on Google Play.

Now, I need to upload a new version of it...but I need "new version code" on the same package...
How to do it with Eclipse?

I hope I'm enough clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, increment the `versionCode`.

```
android:versionCode="1"
```

Comment: What kind of errors? As long as you increment it by an integer, there shouldn't be any problems...

Comment: error: Float types not allowed (at "versioneCode" with value "1.1").

and now, also if I rewrite 1.0, it does not work, it gives me the same errore.

(sorry if answer only now, bad cold)

Comment: @volso The versionCode have to be an integer; 1, 2, 3, etc. You have to increment this value when you want to upload a new version of your app. The versionName can be a float; 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1, etc. This value will be displayed to the users on Google Play.